# Updating table column where one column is max value

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am trying to update one column in a series of about 113000 rows in a table. I have a table where there are a MRN, encounter, and admit columns in question. I have come across an issue where an encounter got entered into this table multiple times, but with different MRNS. I want to update a column called 'Message' with a value 'duplicate encounter' but ONLY if that encounter is not the most current admitted date.

For instance

```
Encounter               MRN                     Admitted
000000000497            0000097778              2006-01-04 20:26:00
000000000497            0000092892              2006-03-17 09:51:00
000000000497            0000003023              2008-08-15 09:50:00
000000000719            0000103691              2008-10-16 14:45:00
000000000719            0000048708              2006-05-26 08:04:00
000000000719            0000024123              2006-01-09 15:43:00
000000003390            0000099595              2006-03-13 11:30:00
000000003390            0000079713              2010-04-22 14:40:00
```

For the above info, I would want to update the message column for line 1 and 2 because line 3 is the most current admitted for encounter 000000000497. Lines 5 and 6 for 000000000719 because line 4 is its most current admit date.

I have tried searching through here but couldn't come up with anything. I just didn't know if I needed to create a cursor for this or what. Any help would be VERY much appreciated.

Comment: for the above, it didnt format how i had it

Comment: encounter 000000000497 would have 3 entries, with MRNs differing...i would update the 2 older admit dates in message column and not do anything to the most current admit date for each encounter distinctly

Comment: What should happen if you have two rows with the same Encounter and same Admitted?

Comment: SQL 2008....no two rows will have the same encounter and same admitted

Here is an example that pulls the max admit date for each encounter
select ENCOUNTER, MAX(admitted)  from his..hpf_enc where ENCOUNTER in(
'000000000497',        
'000000000719',        
'000000003390') group by encounter

I have no idea how to turn that into the opposite update...meaning update the message column IF it is not the max admit date for THAT encoutner

Comment: that is just a sampling of 3 encounters....there are probably about 113900 rows

Comment: even the opposite could work of what was asked
update his..hpf_enc set MESSAGE='max_admit' where ADMITTED=MAX(admitted)

something like that....in a given list of encounters that I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Message = 'Duplicate Encounter'
FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT encounter, MAX(admitted) AS maxadmitted
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY encounter
    HAVING MAX(MRN) <> MIN(MRN)
) b ON a.encounter = b.encounter AND a.admitted <> b.maxadmitted
```

The subselect gets only the encounters that have more than one distinct MRN associated with it, and it also gets the max admitted date for each of those encounters.

We then only update rows where it matches the encounters returned from the subselect, but doesn't update the row with the most recent admitted date.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a subselect to find the most recent `Admitted` for each `Encouter`:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Message = 'Duplicate'
FROM his..hpf_enc AS T1
WHERE Admitted <>
(
    SELECT MAX(Admitted)
    FROM his..hpf_enc AS T2
    WHERE T1.Encounter = T2.Encounter
)
```

You could also use a join:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Message = 'Duplicate'
FROM his..hpf_enc T1
JOIN
(
    SELECT Encounter, MAX(Admitted) AS Admitted
    FROM his..hpf_enc
    GROUP BY Encounter
) AS T2
ON T1.Encounter = T2.Encounter
WHERE T1.Admitted <> T2.Admitted
```

Comment: Your solutions will update all encounters (minus the ones with max admitted dates) regardless of whether or not they have multiple distinct MRNs. I believe the OP only wants to update encounters which have more than one distinct MRN associated with it.

Comment: He says in the question that the MRNs are different.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `RANK()` function.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Message =  'duplicate encounter'
FROM MyTable a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Encounter
            ,MRN
            ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Encounter ORDER BY Admitted DESC) AS RankVal
        FROM MyTable) b
    ON a.Encounter = b.Encounter
    AND a.MRN = b.MRN
    AND b.RankVal <> 1
```